# Display drawable[] with swipe

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable, apk-expansion-files

I want to display some `drawables` recovered from an expansion file into an `imageView`/`Gallery` or something else that can use swipe gestures, 
so I've tried to use :

`imageView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable[]);`

But it returns me that the method `setImageDrawable(Drawable)` in the type `ImageView` is not applicable for the arguments (`Drawable[]`).

What's the proper way to display `Drawables[]` in my case ?

Comment: you will have to use it like Drawables[position] - try view pager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myDrawable[]` is your Drawable array. Not a single drawable.

and the method `imageView.setImageDrawable();` is used for single drawable as an argument.

So use it like,

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable[index]); // index is a key from your drawable array for particular drawable position
```

Comment: Just a supplementary question. Couldn't setImageDrawable be called like this: `imageView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);` and display the first drawable from the array, or it's not the case here? (e.g. isn't the name of the array pointing to the first element?)

Comment: @g00dy - No, In java its not a case, you have to pass an index of element with it.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, it will be of use later ;-) Anyway your answer is correct - upvote.

Comment: @g00dy - What you said is a concept of c, c++ in which array is a continues memory allocation of same data type, so the name of array pointing to first element of array. But in Java it has different implementation.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's something I inherited from before :-)

Comment: I put my Drawable[] in a ViewPager who's taking imageView with your answer to display the drawables. (My Drawable[] is filled like this : `"Drawable.createFromStream(expansionFile.getInputStream("amiante_plombier_ce_1.png"), "src")`) it took like 5s to load the drawable and exactly the same time to swipe to the next picture, is it possible to have something more effective ?

Comment: Yeah, `LazyLoading` for ImageView. Look at http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: The problem is coming from my function "count = MyDrawables[].length;", it is looping many time before returning a result.